# I Can't try out my new app on my iPhone-Gamesalad

Tags: iphone, xcode6, iphone-developer-program, gamesalad

it gives me this error:

---

The version of iOS on “My IPhone” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on Roberto's Iphone
8.1 (12B411)

Xcode Supported iOS Versions

---

i've read about this problem, but all te answers says to update xcode, but now i have xcode 6.1 and nothing is still working

Comment: What is your project build target?

Answer (score 0):

I am not using xcode. I am using gamesalad, so i don't know how to answer you.
the error occours just after i registered the device for testing

Comment: Downloaded GameSalad. I'll see if I can track down the issue with my device (Running iOS 8.1)